# Bright reflections in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

(This question is with regard to v2.80)
I'd like to make a material that reflects a larger amount of light than it would otherwise. I am using a Principled BSDF. In EEVEE I can simply crank the specularity up to 1,000, but that does not seem to work in Cycles.

How might I go about this?

Comment: What effect specifically do you have in mind? A mirror?

Comment: I was thinking something more reminiscent of a highly reflective street sign—though of course, with more control (and not quite 100% physically accurate).

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- set a color of Glossy shader with values greater than 1.0 (click and type the numbers in)
- add multiple Glossy shaders together with the Add node (this breaks the energy conservation and makes the object reflect more light than it receives)